# SQL date time variable

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use this:

```
    VAR v_start_date VARCHAR2(30);
    EXEC :v_start_date := to_date('03-06-2013 04:00:00 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');
    VAR v_end_date VARCHAR2(30);
    EXEC :v_end_date := to_date('04-06-2013 04:00:00 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');

    print v_start_date
    print v_end_date
```

My output gets shortened to this:

```
    v_start_date                  
    ------------------------------
    03-JUN-13                     

    v_end_date                    
    ------------------------------
    04-JUN-13
```

How can I make the variables retain the time of day?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Oracle?  It matters intensely, especially in the area of date and time, where each system is different from the others (at least in parts).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
VAR v_start_date VARCHAR2(30);
EXEC :v_start_date := to_date('03-06-2013 04:00:00 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');
VAR v_end_date VARCHAR2(30);
EXEC :v_end_date := to_date('04-06-2013 04:00:00 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');

print to_char(v_start_date,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');
print to_char(v_end_date,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM');
```

**Edit**

For more information regarding to_char:

[to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly converting the datetime value returned by to_date when assigning it to a varchar.  You should use explicitly convert it `to_char` with an appropriate style, such as:

```
EXEC :v_start_date := to_char(
    to_date('03-06-2013 04:00:00 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM'), 
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

Either format the date with `TO_CHAR` as already pointed out, or to have all dates output with century and time for the current SQLPlus session, set the session date format with this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';
```

Any dates queried after that point will be in the specified format.

To reset to the usual Oracle default:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';
```

The Oracle `DATETIME` formatting codes are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)